# Como abrir um form dentro de um modal com Rails 4 e Foundation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho um cadastro de produtos no Rails. Estou utilizando o Zurb-Foundation 5 como lib no Front-End. Como faço pra chamar um formulário de inclusão dentro de uma Janela modal no Foundation. Eu criei um partial com o form e tentei inseri-lo dentro da `div` a ser chamada no momento do clique mas não dá certo. Tentando ser mais específico pra facilitar. Tenho a URL:

```
localhost:3000/products
```

A ação index já deve listar todos os produtos disponíveis e ao mesmo tempo mostrar o botão de inclusão. Ao clicar no botão, deve abrir o modal com o danado do formulário de inclusão. Queria fazer as operações de CRUD sem alterar a URL para /new, /product/:id e etc. O que eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Um pouco difícil sem ver o código, mas vamos lá: você criou sua partial? (seguindo o _) e depois basta usar: <%= render partial: "partial" %>

Comment: Sim amigo. Criei o partial. O problema dessa abordagem que vc citou, é o seguinte:

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço o Zurb-Foundation, mas tente o seguinte:

Configure a ação *new* do controlador para não renderizar nenhum layout:

```
def new
  [...]
  render :new, layout: :none
end
```

Isso fará o Rails enviar apenas o HTML da partial, sem todo o template (`<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>`).

Como te disse, não conheço o Zend-Foundation, mas acho que deve dar certo se tu conseguir pegar esse HTML e "colar" dentro do modal.

Outro jeito seria tu criar o formulário via Javascript mesmo e fazer a requisição post para a ação "create" (ou outra ação que tu quiser). Mas para para isso tu vai ter que desativar
o token de autenticação daquela ação (**[veja na documentação](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html)**).